# How to access a 0750 folder via php script of root?

Tags: php, linux

I have a php script and it owner is ROOT then I want to use it access to other account files and directories but when I try to access a 0750 file or directory I will got an error message say " failed to open dir: Permission denied"!

How can I do? Why the ROOT has no permission?

Comment: How were you running the script? If you run it through the web server, it doesn't run as root.

Comment: I through apache server to run it so how can I run as root via web server?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running apache as root. Every PHP script would have that level of access. You may want to find a solution to your problem that don't put your server to that risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root user definitely has the permission to execute everything, but the problem is, apache doesn't run from root.

To solve this, try change owner of the file to the user who runs apache. Commonly it is `apache` user, but with apache running, you can get it with this command:

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

After that, change the owner of the file (assuming apache user is `apache`):

```
chown apache:apache file.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this does not depend on the owner of the script, but which account executed the script.